# How do I check the functionality of a 4511 x 7 segment display?

Tags: microcontroller, driver, 7segmentdisplay

So this may sound so stupid but I can't find whats the problem. I have created 7 Segment display with BCD and my [4511 Decoder Driver](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4511b.pdf) is getting too hot.

I checked if I have short circuited but I have not. I don't have (yet) a voltage tester so I used a LED and after some tests the volt turned out to be as expected. I tried different breadboards but it was still overheating.

How do I check the functionality of the display? What should I check first?

[image]

Comment: draw the schematic (there's a schematic editor) and please link to the data sheet

Comment: @MarcusMüller - Hi, in order to help, I've updated the OP's question with the 4511 datasheet from TI, to match their device (I think I can see the TI logo). It's not a great quality copy. The NXP datasheet for their version ([HEF4511B](http://tronixstuff.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/HEF4511B.pdf)) is clearer. Pins 1-7 are inputs.

Comment: really, you **must** draw the schematic. There's things in the picture we cannot see, for example, how (whether?) the power supply lines on the upper part of the photo are driven, how you plan to drive your LEDs and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You have left some input pins unconnected i.e. "floating". Doing this is a *bad idea* and can lead to problems, including excessive power consumption i.e. increased IC temperature.

This situation is described in the [Wikipedia page for the 4000 series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4000_series) as follows:

> > An engineer who forgets to 'tie off' (connect the unused gate inputs to VSS or VDD) may find the chip draws excessive current. The problem is caused by biasing in each gate. With the inputs disconnected, the gates may be biased into a mode where the outputs are partially conducting; this leaves the output buffer drawing a great deal of current since it is not fully on or off, creating a low resistance current path between the power supply rails.

You will find similar warnings in other databooks and manuals from the era when those ICs were introduced.

With CMOS devices you *must* ensure that **all** inputs are driven (or pulled-up/down) to either a valid logic low or a valid logic high.

Although the 4000-series is older than the CMOS IC families mentioned here by TI, their document "[Implications of Slow or Floating CMOS Inputs](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/scba004)" explains more about the general problem.

Comment: Just checked it, the same thing happened, I think the chip is done

Comment: @We'reAllMadHere - Hi - I'm not sure what you mean by "checked it"; I hope you mean "fixed it by ensuring all inputs are valid logic levels". :-) "I think the chip is done" - Perhaps yes, because it is possible to permanently damage ICs by leaving inputs floating.

Comment: Yes that's what I mean :p, Originally I left not inputs floating and just created the circuit, but I found out that it was overheating and that's why I removed the inputs and everything else so I can trace back the problem, well 0.50$ wasted, no big deal, its just that I need it the day after tomorrow..

Comment: @We'reAllMadHere - Also note that 4000 CMOS ICs are more static-sensitive than typical TTL. Depending on environmental conditions in your area and what ESD precautions you are taking, that may be more or less relevant. Internal ESD damage in ICs sometimes causes what *appears* to be a mostly working IC, but which gets too hot and has high power consumption (as well as obviously potentially causing more obvious catastrophic damage and associated behaviour)